# Question Regarding Holes

Tags: existence, definitions, nothing

What even are holes? Are they something or nothing? Do they even exist? Sure, you might think me saying that holes do not exist is idiotic but think about it. The existence of holes doesn't make sense in of themselves. I’ll quote an example, say I get a donut and I ate it. Did I eat the hole too? If no, where did it go? Can I go to a restaurant and ask them to give me a donut without the hole?

Comment: See eg SEP article on holes https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/holes/

Comment: Advice for happiness: "*Keep your eye on the donut, and not on the hole.*"

Comment: In electronics, hole refers to an electron going the other way. It is something, just moving away instead of toward. "*The sun rises, and the sun goes down. And hastens to the place it arises.*" - Ecclesiastes

Comment: Quine's pragmatic proposal is to say that holes do not exist and we should say rather that some things have the property of being perforated.

Comment: @Bumble What does ‘perforated’ mean, in a philosophical Quine-type usage?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. The idea is simply that instead of saying, "there exists a hole in x" which commits us to the existence of holes, we say instead Perforated(x) which says x satisfies the predicate 'perforated'. Using a predicate rather than making an existential claim avoids the commitment to existence.

Comment: @Bumble I find that idea troublesome as a linguist. Reason is that it's possible to have a predicate, for example an adjective, with means "has [stick whatever you want in here]s", and which thus presupposes the existence of [whatever you stuck in here]s. The word *perforated* for example might essentially mean *holey*. Bit difficult to say something is *holey* without having to commit to holes. What did other philosophers say about Quine's proposal?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Properties may imply existence but they don't have to. "X is hairy" implies the existence of hairs. But "X is long" does not imply the existence of a thing called length. "X is round" does not imply the existence of a thing called roundness. Length and roundness are properties of a thing, not things themselves, except perhaps as abstract universals. Quine's proposal is that we can treat 'perforated' as a property without existential commitment. It is a partial statement of the shape of a thing.

Comment: @Bumble Properties such as length or roundness, although measurable are not countable, though. Holeyness seems to be different and more like hairiness (although still different in significant aspects). Hairs and holes are both enumerable. Saying that something has a hole or that it has holes is to say something different. And the fact that the grammar seems to reflect real life substantive differences about the host in each situation seems to make this  predicate different to ones involving length or roundness. I find Quine's proposal a bit odd, unless I squint at it a certain way.

Comment: @Bumble Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 8):

In mathematics a **hole** in a closed surface is an obstruction to contract a loop to a single point on the surface without removing the loop from the surface. The number of independent non-contractible loops is an important number to distinguish different surfaces.

Examples: On the sphere S, e.g. on the surface of the earth, each loop can be contracted to the northpole and hence to any arbitrary point. Therefore there are no obstruction, and S has no holes.

On the donought T there exist two independent loops which cannot be contracted to a point. Hence T has 1 hole.

On a pretzel P there exist more than two independent non-contractible loops. Depending on the form of the pretzel there are 4,6,8,... independent non-contractible loops, hence P has 2,3,4,... holes.

The importance of the mathematical result is the fact that one can formalize the concept of a hole of a surface without looking to the **exterior** of the surface, into the ambient space. Instead one counts independent non-contractible loops **on** the surface.

For more information see the mathematical concept of the [fundamental group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group).

Comment: This excellent answer shows the problem with @Marco's.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.But is doesn't seem to address the question about whether you eat the hole.

Answer (score 6):

No, when you eat a donut you eat the donut. The hole is no different to the rest of the space outside the volume occupied by the body of the donut, none of which do you eat. A hole is a term that effectively refers to the shape of whatever surrounds it. When you say the hole 'exists' what you really mean is that the surrounding object definitely has a surface that bounds a cylindrical portion of space.

The problem underlying your question, like many other topics debated in philosophy, is a tendency to take words at their face value rather than thinking through what they are really signifying. We say bricks exist and we say holes exist, but we are using the language in different ways in the two cases.

Comment: "*Eat your words, but don't go hungry. Words have nearly always hung me.*"

Comment: Great answer, but you didn't address the last sentence about donuts without holes.  ;)

Comment: @MichaelHall in UK you certainly can. Doughuts are sold both with and without holes.

Comment: "what you really mean is that the surrounding object definitely has a surface that bounds a cylindrical portion of space" <--- I don't think the space is cylindrical. b) Why must it be space? It isn't usually space. And if it isn't space how should what you're trying to express be put?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Good point. Given your legendary skill with devising crossword clues, and the fact that being dead gives you lots of free time, perhaps you might like to work on an improvement. I agree holes being circular is a cliché, and the hole in a donut could be filled with jam, say, but the task of crafting a succinct expression to cover all the possible circumstances was beyond me.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Is it your belief that describing the hole in terms of the mix of atmospheric gasses present would enhance the OP's understanding?

Comment: @MichaelHall It’s my belief that a hole is a property of the host, and thus probably can’t be usefully be defined by the ‘space’ or whatever fills it.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore., so what is your confusion with this answer?

Comment: This answer cannot tell how many holes are in a drinking straw, for example. Use homology rather than word games, and you'll have a more precise explanation, including the idea that holes have their own dimensionality.

Comment: @MichaelHall I don't feel particularly confused. I don't think that the description given of what people really mean when they say something has a hole in is fully convincing. And MarcOOcraM seems to agree with me somewhat. And while making the un-thing in the middle of the host disappear is beneficial, it seems to have taken the hole away with it, which is not what we want. (Although it does deal with the eating part quite well, of course).

Comment: @MichaelHall I've just seen your 'gasses' comment. I get the feeling that you think I'm being persnickety for  differentiating between air and space. Perhaps my objection would be clearer if I pointed out that the surrounding object may surround metal, or brick or, in fact, donut?  (a chocolatey churro, for example)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore., No, I don't actually believe you are confused.  There is obviously a deep intellect present, I'm just mildly amused when intellectuals debate with fervor the sort of trivial observations that make perfect sense to a young child.  Truly this seems more a definition of terms question than one of philosophy, but what do I know.  But that's why I am here... to learn!  ;)  And no, that doesn't make your "objection" any clearer.  The hole can be filled, and consist of anything except a homogeneous extension of the surrounding material.

Answer (score 2):

A hole cannot exist independently of something else. We cannot have a universe where the only denizen is a hole. It is always a hole in *something* -- it is a feature of an object, not an object itself.

Other examples are "dimples", "bumps", "ripples" or any other topological quality (riffing off of Jo's answer). These are things whose existence depends on something else.

In a different vein, "waves" don't exist in the same way that water does either, they are things "water does" or "about water".

Comment: I would be careful with your appeals to mathematics. The hole in a circle exists in an absolute sense. It doesn't depend on the circle being anything other than a circle. It doesn't even depend on how the circle sits in some higher dimensional space. The same goes for the whole in a donut (which is just a fattened circle).

Comment: @CharlesHudgins What hole in a circle are you referring to?

Comment: The hole that can be detected by the existence of a one-form on the circle (e.g. $d\theta$) that cannot be expressed as the derivative of a function. This is a fact about the circle that intrinsically (i.e. without needing reference to an embedding space) distinguishes it from a line segment (for which no such one-form exists). Mathematicians say that the circle has a hole because of this intrinsic difference.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins - where did I appeal to mathematics apart from very tangentially wrt topological qualities. Also, it's not clear we are detecting the existence of a hole using 1-forms or classifying the topology in a coordinate-free sense.

Comment: Rereading your post I understand your meaning better. I would still quibble that the existence of the hole doesn't *depend* on the circle but is rather (almost precisely) constitutive of the circle in the mathematical sense. But you are right, there is no reason we have to take the mathematicians' word for it. I (wrongly it seems) assumed you were interested in the mathematician's perspective because you mentioned topology.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, "*the existence of the hole doesn't depend on the circle*"  Huh?  If you don't have a circle how can you define the hole?  (on a side note, is "circle" even the right term?  A solid disc forms a circle but without a hole...)

Comment: @MichaelHall Circle is the mathematical term for any space homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ with the endpoints identified. We call a solid disc... a disc. The point is that the circle is somehow the simplest example of a space in which not every loop is contractible. When a loop is not contractible, we say there is a hole in the way of that loop contracting. That is the sense in which I meant that the hole is constitutive of the circle. A circle is special to mathematicians because it's the simplest example of a space with a hole.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, Thanks, I will punt...  My brain works primarily in the physical and pragmatic realm.  On the off chance I might learn something useful yet, briefly and in layman's terms can you help me understand the difference between my disc on the left, and your circle in the middle here?  https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Classes-of-homeomorphic-surfaces-The-digits-below-the-columns-denote-the-number-of_fig6_222448871

Comment: other posts here have already explained the difference better than I could in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

"... say i get a donut and ate it. Did i eat the hole too? If no, where did it go?"

The same place your lap goes when you stand up.

Comment: Answering the question without answering the question :-)  both are concepts that rely on certain physical conditions; when the conditions change the concepts are no longer fulfilled.

Comment: @Frog - I enjoy giving a reply that points out that the questioner knew the answer all along.

Comment: Are you suggesting the OP bend over and take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the Eastern philosophical insight (which dovetails well with Wittgenstein's later work), which is that a 'hole' is defined by use-value. In other words — straight from the Daodejing — the *form* of a cup may be determined by solid clay, but the *use* of a cup is determined by the empty space (the hole) that the clay surrounds. Without that empty space, we don't have a cup.

Analytically then, a 'hole' would be defined as as a volume of space reserved through some material boundary for some human purpose (or contrarily, a similarly bounded volume of space that must be filled or avoided for some human purpose).

A cup has a basin (an open-topped hole) to contain loose materials. A funnel has a basin with a smaller hole at the bottom, to contain and concentrate loose materials into a stream. Donuts and bagels have holes to increase the surface-area-to-volume ratio, ensuring even cooking. Streets have potholes that are a risk to motorists and must be dealt with. If we have a volume of space that we have no particular use for or interest in, or that isn't contained by some material boundary, we don't generally label it a hole.

Answer (score 0):

A hole is nothing that exists within something. A black hole is a good example.

Comment: Your comment is correct. But it doesn't answer the question(s)